# Shouldn't this re.compile() expression find all links in a page?

Tags: python, parsing, hyperlink

I have a lot of difficulty understanding the re.compile() method in python.  I found this example and from what I read it should find all links in a webpage.  Is this correct?  Can someone explain the "(.*?) part of the expression?  It's not making much sense to me, and it doesn't seem to be finding the links in a page.

```
link_finder = re.compile('href="(.*?)"')
links = link_finder.findall(html)
```

Comment: use beautifulsoup, forget about parsing   html with just regex

Comment: Ya that's what I'm going to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
"(.*?)"
```

This is a non-greedy expression to match all characters between a pair of double-quotes. Non-greedy means that **as soon** as it finds the **next** double quote it will stop searching.

In contrast, a greedy expression

```
"(.*)"
```

Won't stop at the next double-quotes it finds - it will continue until it hits the last one on the current line - hence the word "greedy", and not what you need in this case.

It's possible that it's not finding anything for you because all your links are quoted using `single-quotes` instead of `double-quotes`. In that case, try

```
link_finder = re.compile("href='(.*?)'")
```

instead (note the positions of the single and double quotes are swapped)

Example output:

```
>>> link_finder = re.compile("href='(.*?)'")
>>> links = link_finder.findall("<a href='testlink'>")
>>> links
['testlink']
```

**EDIT:**

As a disclaimer, I should note that there are still better ways to do this. One is as follows:

```
re.compile("href\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]")
```

Which will match spaces as well as match both types of quotes. But even better as Ken Hampson suggests is to use a dedicated tool for this [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Thanks!!! This explains a lot.  I couldn't find it simplified like that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

To truly find all the *HTML* links in a document, it's more nuanced than that regex would support.

For example, either of these tags are valid HTML:

```
<a href='foo.html'>foo</a>

<a href = 'foo2.html'>foo2</a>
```

But your *regex* would only find the first one.

One could alter the regex to account for that, yes, i.e.:

```
link_finder = re.compile("href\s*=\s*'(.*?)'")
```

But there are other nuances beyond that (single vs. double quote pairs is just one other example), and this gets back into the whole thing about it really not being a good idea to use a *regex* to parse *HTML* (nor *XML*, etc.). It's really best to use an actual *HTML* parser to do that, as all of these nuances are accounted for since the parser has to account for the whole *grammar* of the language.

If you're operating in a web context, *jQuery* may actually be the best bet, since that will search the *DOM* via a one-liner.

For pure Python, *lxml* is one possibility (http://lxml.de/).